# How Laravel Where Query works with optional parameter passing

Tags: php, laravel

Hi guys I was wondering how this works. Can someone please explain

Internally defined Laravel Where method

```
public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
```

My Controller

```
User::where('id',2)->get();
```

This pulls User ID 2

So my question is how does Laravel know 2 is a value and not an operator

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Query/Builder.php#L583) they describe it how they are identifying based on the number of argument passed to the function.